# spring mvc matching a url and using as variable

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Foo/{id}/{friendlyUrl:*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getFoo(@PathVariable final Long id, @PathVariable final String friendlyUrl, final Principal principal) {
/* then match friendlyUrl, 
 * if it doesn't match use redirect 
 * view to send to correct place*/
}
```

Where I use the asterix my ide is coming back with an error ?

Comment: What do you want to express with the asterisk? I see this style of pattern only here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex but thats a different use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to use regex for matching then I guess what you want is

```
"/Foo/{id}/{friendlyUrl:.*}"
```

As per the [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex) the pattern must be `{varName:regex}`.